# How to Get lat and long Data from LAC-CELLId using php?

Tags: php

This code return `null` value. Value is: `{}`

I checked it, CURL is enabled but still it returns `null -> {}`. Do you get the results?

Please help me asap.

PHP code is blow:

```
$urlstring="http://www.google.com/loc/json";
$ch=curl_init($urlstring);

$cell_towers = array();
$row=new stdClass();
$row->location_area_code=3311;
$row->mobile_network_code=71;
$row->cell_id=32751;
$row->mobile_country_code=404;
$cell_towers[]=$row;    
$param = array(
  'host'=> 'localhost',
  'version' => '1.1.0', 
  'request_address' => true,
  'cell_towers' => $cell_towers
);

$param_json=json_encode($param);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `new stdClass()` with a simple `array()`.

Also did you try to `echo $param_json`? Is the data properly formatted?

Finally, I'm surprised the POSTFIELDS is the whole JSON data. Are you sure it shouldn't be something like `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("data" => $param_json))`?